# how to visualize geodata (Points) in databricks builtin map?

Tags: maps, data-visualization, databricks, azure-databricks

I simply have a dataframe of "lat" and "lon" coordinates that I would like to visualize on a map.

[image]

[image]

I am trying to view my data data on the map. But nothing is being displayed. 
In my case, the mmsi is the id.

Please note that I have around 2M points to display. Is that possible in databricks?

If there is no way around (plotting 2,000,000 points) in databricks, then what tool can handle large amount of data?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Do you need the lat/lon plotted or just the aggregated values of each region?

Comment: @RaphaelK, I want to plot only the lat/lon

Comment: ok, gotcha.  What language are you using?

Comment: I'm using python exactly, "pycharm"

Answer (score 4):

The built in map does not support latitude / longitude data points.

Delivering 2 million data points directly to a browser is problematic. Databricks has a protective limit of 20 MB for HTML display. Your viewers won't be able to take in and visually process that level of detail at any point in time.

I recommend implementing a filter/summarization strategy to enable the display within Databricks notebooks. Some ideas can be taken from this Databricks post: https://databricks.com/blog/2019/12/05/processing-geospatial-data-at-scale-with-databricks.html

Also this Anaconda post gives an excellent survey of data visualization packages, some (like Datashader, Vaex) implement a visual summarization strategies before rendering images: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/python-data-visualization-2018-why-so-many-libraries

Answer (score 2):

The error message clearly says that " Unrecognizable values in the first column. The values should be either country codes in ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 format (e.g. "GBR") or US state abbreviations (e.g. "TX")."

**Note:** To plot a graph of the world, use [country codes in ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3) **as the key**.

- **A Map Graph is a way to visualize your data on a map.**
- **Plot Options**... was used to configure the graph below.
- **Keys should** contain the field with the **location**.
- **Series groupings** is always ignored for World Map graphs.
- **Values** should contain exactly one field with a **numerical value**.
- Since there can multiple rows with the same location key, choose "Sum", "Avg", "Min", "Max", "COUNT" as the way to combine the values for a single key.
- Different values are denoted by color on the map, and ranges are always spaced evenly.

**Reference:** [Databricks - Charts and Graph](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/charts-and-graphs-python.html)

[image]

Hope this helps.